# telerik radgrid .net export button issue on chrome

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-reporting

I have a radgrid on my webform with an export button displayed. My issue here is that on IE and Mozilla, when you click the button it'll pop up a download window for the csv. But for chrome it would immediately display the data on the browser itself. So you have to do a work around to save the export on a separate file.

Was wondering if there's any setting I should be setting up to prevent this and just have the pop up window show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No setting adjustments needed, because it's already been fixed and is in the next stable release for chrome:

[Issue 152911:     CSV files open as text not downloading](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=152911#c58)

> There's nothing to update you on. The fix has been merged to the
>   stable branch and will be in the next regular stable release. We do
>   not give predicted dates for our releases as too many factors can
>   affect them.
>
> -Comment 59

I'd just be patient as the Chrome team has already addressed this.

Comment: @gdubs Np, the non-technical answers are the worst to find :)